# New Moderator Appointment Announcement

Tags: discussion

We had a bit of a mod shakeup recently. No worries, it's all been sorted out now, but I felt it best to make the announcement!

We've appointed **eldarerathis** as a new moderator for Android.SE!

[image: eldarerathis]

eldarerathis was the first runner-up in the Android election, and we're very happy to welcome eldar aboard!

In related news, our favorite suited droid mod has had to step down for a number of reasons. We appreciate all the hard work that **Al Everett** has put into Android.SE and understand his stepping down.

[image: Al Everett]

Al will continue to be a valued member of our community, and we're sure you'll see him around the site, contributing awesome answers and helping cultivate this community.

We wish both users all the best moving forward! :D

Comment: @eldarerathis: Thank _you_ for stepping up and filling the void.

Comment: @eldarerathis congratulations! Welcome to the team!

Comment: @AlEverett Thank you for all the work you've put in, we really appreciate everything you have done here

Comment: @AlEverett Thanks for all the effort, don't be a stranger. Congrats eldarerathis you deserve it, good luck.

Comment: @GAThrawn: Well, now I've cracked 10K. You'll never be rid of me! In all seriousness, I'll be around as often as I can. It's just that lately (and for the foreseeable future) that's not often enough to be an effective Moderator (in my estimation).